# Java Net: Code example about when we need to extends SocketImpl Abstract class & implement SocketImplFactory interface from user define applications

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I was reading Java Net docs for Sockets and found that, `java.net.Socket` class define the Java sockets API , but delegate all their actions to SocketImpl Abstract class,As this class is Abstract, subclass will extend this abstract `java.net.SocketImpl` class.Later the object of this subclass will run as the actual Socket implementation.The Socket Factory object will be created by interface SocketImplFactory and will be used to call `java.net.SocketImplFactory.createSocketImpl()`to create that object of the subclass of `java.net.SocketImpl`.If i am understanding correctly (please let me know if i misunderstood anything), then do user application need create subclass of `java.net.SocketImpl` and implements  `interface SocketImplFactory` ? I think so , because they also said that some situations where we need to do it like: socket behind Firewall, Proxy.Can anybody please provide me very easy code samples to understand it.Please help me. I am stuck on that for the lack of good code examples.I googled for such clear examples but found very complex examples [(like this one)](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.net.SocketImplFactory) without any main method to test it.Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't understand why you want to mess with Socket implementation? Maybe this clears some things: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Hi @Fildor, thanks for your reply.So are you saying i don't need to define any subclasss of `java.net.SocketImpl ` and don't need to  implements  interface `SocketImplFactory` at all.Java socket library will manage such internal mess by itself, we just need to call Socket methods.is it? thanks

Comment: That's what an API is for. You just use it. Smart people with a lot of resources made the effort to write all that for you, test it and review it. You would need a _very_ good reason not to use the default implementations the JDK is giving you.

Comment: thanks @Fildor for raply, Now i got it, earlier i was confused what they write about ScoketImpl on this link [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html)

Comment: I see. You were already "behind the curtain". So, you were looking into how to build a car, when you only want to drive one :)